# Replace entry in Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

If I create a dictionary in Python,

```
x = {'a': {'b': 5, 'c': 6}, 'c':{'d': 10}}
```

and would like to replace one entry as follows:

```
x = {'a': {'b': 5, 'e': 4}, 'c':{'d': 10}}
```

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what exactly was the problem?

Comment: You would have to remove the `x['a']['c']` entry and assign a value to `x['a']['e']`.  Hint: `del` and `=` will come in handy here

Comment: I can of course replace the complete entry like,
    x['a'] = {'b': 5, 'e': 4}
but in that case I would need to somehow delete just the 'c': 6 part and insert the 'e': 4 part. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to do is not a replacement. It's two operations.

1. Delete `c` key from your dict: `del x['a']['c']`
2. Add a new value to the dic: `x['a']['e']=4`

To replace value of the same key, you just assign a new value to the key, `x['a']['c']=15`